# Manage global Backbone events while writing Qunit unit tests

Tags: backbone.js, qunit

I am writing unit tests for my Backbone app. Certain tests trigger events, which is causing interference among the different tests.

Here are my tests

```
test('user setting a company should update the departmentslists url', function() {
    var Acme = new Company({ id:274, name: "Acme Solutions" });
    var companies = new CompanyList;
    var departments = new DepartmentList;
    new CompanySelectorView({ el: '#company-input', collection: companies });

    events.trigger('userSet:company', Acme);

    equal(_.result(departments, 'url'), 'http://'+document.location.host+'/data/companies/274/departments');
});

asyncTest('user setting a company should retrieve that companys departments', function() {
    var Acme = new Company({ id:274, name: "Acme Solutions" });
    var companies = new CompanyList;
    var departments = new DepartmentList;
    new CompanySelectorView({ el: '#company-input', collection: companies });

    events.trigger('userSet:company', Acme);

    events.on('fetched:departments', function(response) {
        deepEqual(response, [{id: "8",name: "Accounting"},{id: "1",name: "Client Services"},{id: "470",name: "Systems"},{id: "1187",name: "Managers"}]);
        start();
    })

});
```

and the relevant part of my collection:

```
var DepartmentList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;

        events.on("userSet:company", function(company) {
            self.selectedCompany = company;
            self.fetch({
                success: function(collection, response, options) {
                    events.trigger("fetched:departments", response);
                }
            });
        });
    },

    model: Department,

    selectedCompany: '',

    url: function() {
        return 'http://'+document.location.host+'/data/companies/'+this.selectedCompany.id+'/departments';
    }

});
```

What's the solution here? I want to split these two tests out from each other, since they're different things, but I also want the event trigger included in my test.

PS: I'm new to Backbone & unit testing, any criticism is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to solve this is to use `events.once` instead of `events.on`. This way your events are cleaned up after each test.